# If $C$ has full column rank and $C'1_M=0$ then $C(C'C)^{-1}C'=I_M-1_M(1_M'1_M)^{-1}1_M'$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Supposing that $M>0$ is a positive integer, we define $1_M$ (dimension $M\times 1$) as a column vector of $1$'s and let
>   $$
> Q\equiv I_M-1_M(1_M'1_M)^{-1}1_M'
> $$
>   be the projection matrix that projects off the space spanned by $1_M$. Hayashi (2000) claims that if $C$ is **any** $M\times (M-1)$ matrix of full column rank s.t. $C'1_M=0$, then
>   $$
> P_C\equiv C(C'C)^{-1}C'=Q.
> $$
>   How do I prove this please? Thank you for your time.

I tried to prove that $P_Cx=Qx$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^M$ but I couldn't get very far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constant vector $1_M$ spans the nullspace of $C'$; this follows from $C'1_M=0$ and the fact that $C'$ has rank $M-1$. Hence $\mathbb{C}^M=\mathrm{Im}(C)\oplus\mathrm{Ker}(C')=\mathrm{Im}([C,1_M])$, that is, $[C,1_M]$ is a square nonsingular matrix. Consequently,
$$
P_C-Q=0\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad (P_C-Q)[C,1_M]=0\quad\Leftrightarrow (P_C-Q)C=0\quad\&\quad (P_C-Q)1_M=0.
$$
Now substitute the expressions for $P_C$ and $Q$ to verify the last two equations.

Comment: Thank you very much. Please give me a bit of time to digest.